# Is it possible to extend a KineticJS event handler, specifially the _touchend() handler for draggable objects?

Tags: javascript, events, html5-canvas, kineticjs

I have some draggable KineticJS image objects on a layer and I want to execute my own handler on the 'touchend' event. Sounds simple enough! I have added handlers to each of my images objects, for example:

```
toyKinObj.on('touchend', openBoxContactEnded);
```

However because the 'draggable' property is 'true' for the objects, it seems that KineticJS is also calling its built-in _touchend() handler in addition to my own handler code.

My code does things stage.clear() and e.shape.setDraggable(false) but these object modifications seem to interfere with the built-in _touchend() handler. Depending on which version of my code I'm using, I have seen the KineticJS _handleEvent() handler fail because the event has no longer exists, or images on the layer I cleared later re-appear (the latter might occur because I KineticJS is attempting to re-draw the stage/layers as part of it's event handling, even though I wanted to clear the stage).

To make matters a bit more complicated, it also seems that my own handler code is being called in the middle of the built-in KineticJS _touchend() handler code, which I'm sure doesn't help.

So my question is: instead of having my own handler, can I extend the _touchend() handler to execute my code after the main _touchend() code? Or somehow ensure that my code doesn't execute until _touchend() is done? i.e. control the order of handler execution?

I could hack _touchend() to dispatch a user-defined event when it's finished, to trigger my own code, or I could forget about the KineticJS touch events and implement my own drag/drop handlers, but I'm sure I'm just missing something and there's an easier way.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is canceling event propagation, try:

```
  shape.on('touched', function(evt) {
    evt.cancelBubble = true;
  });
```

More info: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-cancel-event-bubble-propagation-with-kineticjs/